# Need help with a .bat script for parsing W3C logs

Tags: ftp, scripting, w3c, batch-file

Im trying to get a value (IP address) from a W3C logfile (kinda like a text file). This is  what I have so far but with no luck:

```
Set filename=ex%date:~-2,4%%date:~-10,2%%date:~-7,2%.log

For /F "tokens=2 delims=: . " %%A in ('E:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles\MSFTPSVC6141885\%filename%') do (Set ip=%%A)
```

and the log file looks like:

```
# Software: Microsoft Internet Information Services 6.0
# Version: 1.0
#Date: 2009-01-10 20:58:16
#Fields: time c-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem sc-status sc-win32-status 
#20:58:16 10.10.1.111 [25]USER anonymous 331 0
```

so the IP adress is on the 5th line second column (10.10.1.111)

any feedback would be appreciated!

Comment: Could you indent your code and logfile 4 spaces for each line? I think the formatting is ruining some of the data being presented.

Answer (score 3):

Have you tried [Microsoft Log Parser](http://www.microsoft.com/technet/scriptcenter/tools/logparser/default.mspx)? Supposedly it supports W3C-style log files out-of-the-box. I don't know what you're trying to do, but it might be easier than hand-crafting a batch file.

Alternatively, install AWK (e.g. from Cygwin). Or even Perl -- this is its raison-d'etre.

Answer (score 1):

Change your `for` line to this:

```
For /F "skip=4 tokens=2" %%A in (E:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles\MSFTPSVC6141885\%filename%) do (
    Set ip=%%A
    goto :DONE
)
:DONE
@echo IP = %ip%
:: Continue script
```

`skip=4` will ignore the first four lines of the log file and start parsing the 5th.
You need the `goto` to stop from parsing the rest of the lines in the file, otherwise you'll spin through the whole file and `ip` would equal the second token of the last line, which may or may not be the IP address.

The default delimiter is space, so you don't need to change this with a `delims` arg. You do want just the second token, which is the IP address.

You don't need to enclose the filename in single quotes, since you're parsing the contents of the file, not the filename string. If the filename has embedded spaces you would have to use this `for` line instead:

```
For /F "usebackq skip=4 tokens=2" %%A in ("E:\WINDOWS\system32\LogFiles\MSFTPSVC6141885\%filename%") do (
```